# How am I supposed to check a qualifier value in EDI

Tags: xml, edi

It failed in VAN due to 02 qualifier. That is your qualifier correct?

ISA*00*          *00*          *ZZ*REDACTED       *02*REDACTED           *221026*1645*U*00401*000000016*0*T*@

I just want to know how I can verify that it is indeed 02..

I just want to know how I can verify that it is indeed 02..

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

The ISA05/ISA06 (sender) and ISA07/ISA08 (receiver) are qualifier/ID pairs.  ISA05 indicates what ISA06 is.  For example, if ISA05 is 12, one should be able to expect a phone number in ISA06.  12 means phone number.

VANs will use qualifier/IDs as identifiers to know how to route the data.  If they're telling you the 02 qualifier is wrong, you need to ask your trading partner what their ISA IDs are.